# javascript how to trigger "Alt+E +E" keyboard action

Tags: javascript, safari

I need to access Safari Menu options to reset browser settings. How to achieve this using Javascript.

Manual Actions are as follows

> ALT + E + E
>
> click Tab (10 times)
>
> Click on Enter button

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Safari isn't going to provide such API for JS at least for security reasons. I think it may be possible in [Safari extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).